# Extracting Values from XML node using variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following sql query and want to get the values of only the CURCVY node values from 1-4 so I can insert each node to a table. but all it inserts are the node names

```
   DECLARE
   @MYARRAY table (TEMPCOL nvarchar(50)),
   @tvar char(100),
   @cnt INT = 1,
   @cnt_total int =5, 
   @xmldata xml='<NewDataSet>
   <ROWS>
    <POLIAGIN>PRE-AUTHORIZED</POLIAGIN>
    <CURCVY01>0.00</CURCVY01>
    <CURCVY02>253.00</CURCVY02>
    <CURCVY03>1523.50</CURCVY03>
    <CURCVY04>2815.50</CURCVY04>
    <CURCVY05>4129.00</CURCVY05>
  </ROWS>
</NewDataSet>'

WHILE @cnt < @cnt_total
BEGIN
set @tvar = 'CURCVY0'+ cast(@cnt as char(5))
   EXEC sp_insert_to_my_table @xmldata.query('NewDataSet/ROWS/*').value('(sql:variable("@tvar"))[1]','nvarchar(max)') 
   SET @cnt = @cnt + 1; 
END;
```

this is what the sp does

```
--sp_insert_to_my_table

declare
@amount as vachar(max)

insert into myTable (column1)
values (@amount)
```

UPDATE

I've tried the following method and now I get null values

```
EXEC sp_insert_to_my_table @xmldata.value('(/NewDataSet/ROWS/*[local-name() = sql:variable("@tvar")])[1]','nvarchar(max)')
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Will add more detail and examples

Answer (score 0):

Guessing what you need.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @maxValue CHAR(2) = '04'
, @xmldata XML = 
N'<NewDataSet>
   <ROWS>
    <CURCVY01>0.00</CURCVY01>
    <CURCVY02>253.00</CURCVY02>
    <CURCVY03>1523.50</CURCVY03>
    <CURCVY04>2815.50</CURCVY04>
    <CURCVY05>4129.00</CURCVY05>
  </ROWS>
</NewDataSet>';

SELECT c.value('text()[1]', 'decimal(10,2)') AS Result
FROM @xmldata.nodes('/NewDataSet/ROWS/*[substring(local-name(.),7,2) le sql:variable("@maxValue")]') AS t(c)
```

**Output**

```
+---------+
| Result  |
+---------+
|    0.00 |
|  253.00 |
| 1523.50 |
| 2815.50 |
+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is the code you need:

```sql
DECLARE
  @maxValue int = 4,
  @xmldata xml='
<NewDataSet>
   <ROWS>
    <POLIAGIN>PRE-AUTHORIZED</POLIAGIN>
    <CURCVY01>0.00</CURCVY01>
    <CURCVY02>253.00</CURCVY02>
    <CURCVY03>1523.50</CURCVY03>
    <CURCVY04>2815.50</CURCVY04>
    <CURCVY05>4129.00</CURCVY05>
  </ROWS>
</NewDataSet>';

INSERT myTable (column1)
SELECT x.CURCVY.value('text()[1]','decimal(18,5)')
FROM @xmldata.nodes('NewDataSet/ROWS/*[substring(local-name(), 1, 6) = "CURCVY"][position() <= 4]') x(CURCVY);
```

Note how the `position()` predicate is separate, therefore it only begins counting after the `substring()` has filtered.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e3c4d837652e4d3aea0cf59a64bb78b0)